# How can I replicate a monthly data across weeks in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, replication

I have monthly data from Jan 2016 to July 2020. I need it replicated across weeks starting Monday.

I tried using resample and ffill() but because the periods are same across various cities and cars, I'm unable to use it.

*`*df = df.resample('W-MON').ffill()*`*

I'm getting the following error:

```
***ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit.***
```

The original df is as follows:

```
Car type    num_month   Sales   City    Car model
P       01-01-2016     100     X       A
P       01-02-2016     200     X       A
Q       01-01-2016     223     X       B
Q       01-02-2016     123     X       B
R       01-01-2016     456     X       C
R       01-02-2016     678     X       C
S       01-01-2016     345     X       D
S       01-02-2016     123     X       D
T       01-01-2016     876     X       E
T       01-02-2016     567     X       E
U       01-01-2016     780     X       F
U       01-02-2016     543     X       F
P       01-01-2016     766     Y       A
P       01-02-2016     465     Y       A
Q       01-01-2016     452     Y       B
Q       01-02-2016     1234    Y       B
R       01-01-2016     353     Y       C
R       01-02-2016     566     Y       C
S       01-01-2016     564     Y       D
```

The required file goes like:

```
Car type    num_month       Week        Sales    City   Car model
    P       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      100     X       A
    Q       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      223     X       B
    R       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      456     X       C
    U       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      780     X       F
    S       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      345     X       D
    T       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      876     X       E
    P       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      100     X       A
    Q       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      223     X       B
    R       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      456     X       C
    U       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      780     X       F
    S       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      345     X       D
    T       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      876     X       E
    P       01-01-2016      18-01-2016      100     X       A
    Q       01-01-2016      18-01-2016      223     X       B
    R       01-01-2016      18-01-2016      456     X       C
    U       01-01-2016      18-01-2016      780     X       F
    S       01-01-2016      18-01-2016      345     X       D
    T       01-01-2016      18-01-2016      876     X       E
    P       01-01-2016      25-01-2016      100     X       A
    Q       01-01-2016      25-01-2016      223     X       B
    R       01-01-2016      25-01-2016      456     X       C
    U       01-01-2016      25-01-2016      780     X       F
    S       01-01-2016      25-01-2016      345     X       D
    T       01-01-2016      25-01-2016      876     X       E
    P       01-02-2016      01-02-2016      200     X       A
    Q       01-02-2016      01-02-2016      123     X       B
    R       01-02-2016      01-02-2016      678     X       C
    U       01-02-2016      01-02-2016      564     X       F
    S       01-02-2016      01-02-2016      123     X       D
    T       01-02-2016      01-02-2016      567     X       E
    P       01-02-2016      08-02-2016      200     X       A
    Q       01-02-2016      08-02-2016      123     X       B
    R       01-02-2016      08-02-2016      678     X       C
    U       01-02-2016      08-02-2016      564     X       F
    S       01-02-2016      08-02-2016      123     X       D
    T       01-02-2016      08-02-2016      567     X       E
    P       01-02-2016      15-02-2016      200     X       A
    Q       01-02-2016      15-02-2016      123     X       B
    R       01-02-2016      15-02-2016      678     X       C
    U       01-02-2016      15-02-2016      564     X       F
    S       01-02-2016      15-02-2016      123     X       D
    T       01-02-2016      15-02-2016      567     X       E
    P       01-02-2016      22-02-2016      200     X       A
    Q       01-02-2016      22-02-2016      123     X       B
    R       01-02-2016      22-02-2016      678     X       C
    U       01-02-2016      22-02-2016      564     X       F
    S       01-02-2016      22-02-2016      564     X       D
    T       01-02-2016      22-02-2016      567     X       E
    P       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      766     Y       A
    Q       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      452     Y       B
    R       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      353     Y       C
    U       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      456     Y       F
    S       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      564     Y       D
    T       01-01-2016      04-01-2016      230     Y       E
    P       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      766     Y       A
    Q       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      452     Y       B
    R       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      353     Y       C
    U       01-01-2016      11-01-2016      456     Y       F
```

Along with this, if a week's start date is 27 or greater such that most of the week falls into the next month then that week's data is to be included only in the next month that is if week date is 29-06-16, the respective month or "num_month" for the same will be 01-07-2016.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Make sure to thouroughly read the guideline for posting questions. As a rule, post data in correct format and post your own attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the the `datetime` package. The `datetime.date.today().isocalendar()` returns today's year (2020), week of the year(48), and day of the week(6).

Below, I've replicated a value for each day in the month.  You could do this for the week as well.

```
import datetime

jan_2020_val = 2
feb_2020_val = 3
jan_2021_val = 4
feb_2021_val = 5


curr_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)
mydata = []
while curr_date < end_date:
    if curr_date.month == 1 and curr.date.year == 2020:
        mydata.append((curr_date, jan_2020_val))
    if curr_date.month == 2 and curr_date.year == 2020:
        mydata.append((curr_date, feb_2020_val))
    if curr_date.month == 1 and curr_date.year == 2021:
        mydata.append((curr_date, jan_2021_val))
    if curr_date.month == 2 and curr_date.year == 2021:
        mydata.append((curr_date, feb_2021_val)) 
    curr_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(mydata)
```

Comment: I need this to be done for a period of 4 years or more. Jan_val and feb_val variables won't work for that.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to incorporate additional years.  You might also look at the `np.select`  function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. This didn't exactly get the correct results though. I've updated my question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by first creating a **pivot table**, so all the car models form an individual column. Then using a ***for loop*** for each city, I resampled the data using **pd.df.resample.ffill()** and ultimately unpivoted the data using **melt()**. However, for the last month, I'm still getting just the date of the first week. But that is all I managed to get.